# double to int conversion not working using math.h functions in c

Tags: c, int, double, type-conversion, math.h

```
dataBuf[1] = acos(0.130f);
```

This is the code I'm running but when I print out the result, it comes out as 1 instead of 82. dataBuf is an int16_t array. All the other math.h functions work fine with the conversion but the trig ones don't work.

Comment: Trig is in radians, not degrees.

Comment: and confirmed, I'm an idiot

Comment: `acos(0.130f) * 180 /  M_PIl`

Comment: `acos` takes an argument of type `double` (and returns a result of the same type). `acos(0.130)` would make a lot more sense. If you really want to use `float`, use `acosf(0.130f)`. For future reference, don't just tell us you printed the result, show us *how*. A common error (which you apparently didn't make here) is to use the wrong `printf` specifier.

Comment: @Keith Thompson I'm using this on a micro controller, and transmitting the result through UART. I thought it would make the question more complicated so I decided not to put it in.

Comment: `acos()` returns a value in the range 0 to π radians, so where does 82 come from, and why do you assign its return value to `int16_t`?

Comment: @WeatherVane: I think we've already established that the OP was (incorrectly) expecting a result in degrees. acos(0.13) is close to 82 degrees.

Comment: @KeithThompson, yes but the `int16_t` has not been mentioned. I don't understand your comments about an error in the `printf` format specifier since that is not part of the question and you don't think OP did it anyway. Please stop talking down to me, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trigonometric functions in `math.h` use radians, not degrees. You can convert the radians to degrees by multiplying by `180 / pi`, ( `57.29577951308232`).

`acos(0.13)` would return `1.440427347091751` radians which multiplied by `57.29577951308232` gives the result of `82.53040768358306` degrees.

Answer (score 0):

OP is expecting result in degrees yet `acos()` returns a result in radians as well explained by [@Antti Haapala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/918959/antti-haapala).

Further, OP code experiences `int` truncation rather than rounding.  Example:  when trying to calculate a result of 90 degrees.  `acos(0)` --> `1.570796...`.  When this value is converted into degrees, the result may be just less than `90.0` as in `89.999999999...`.  When this is converted to `int16_t` the result is truncated to 89 and not the hoped for `90`.  Best to *round* floating point values before converting to an integer.

```
dataBuf[1] = (int16_t) round(acos(0.130f) * 180/M_PI);`
// or using float functions
const float r2d = 180/M_PI;
dataBuf[1] = (int16_t) roundf(acosf(0.130f) * r2d);`
```